# проблема с разделением строки на Артиста и название трека

Tags: objective-c, ios, регулярные-выражения, строки

Делаю приложение (радио) и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Данные о треке поступают одной строкой вида:

> **Артист - Название трека**

в консоли это выглядит так

> App_FM[8201:280206] SONG META
>   StreamTitle='Артист - Название трека’;

разложил эту строку так:

> **Артист**
>
> **Название трека**

с помощью данного кода

```
-(void)updateTitle:(NSString*)title {
// update view text

NSArray *piecesOfOriginalString = [title componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];

title = [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"StreamTitle='(.*)"
                                   withString:@"$1" 
                                      options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0] length])];


NSString *title_track = [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(.*)';" withString:@"$1"
     options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
        range:NSMakeRange(0, [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1] length])];

NSLog (@"=====================================");
NSLog (@"Испольнитель: %@", title);
NSLog (@"Название трека: %@", title_track);
NSLog (@"=====================================");


[self.trackTitle setText:title];
[self.trackTitle_label setText:title_track];

}
```

Все работает, если играет трек. Но вот если вместо трека будет надпись "Новости" (Одно слово)

Пример

> 2015-08-02 19:01:41.907 App_FM[8201:280206] SONG META
>   StreamTitle='Новости’;

то приложение вылетает с ошибкой

> 2015-08-02 19:03:12.299 App_FM[8223:280652] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***
>   -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x26283137 0x3470dc77 0x26195217 0x8bc21 0x8fb7b 0x8fda3 0x902e5
>   0x25dc2049 0x25dc2003 0x25dc20f5 0x25daf801 0x25cd3a53 0x25d7324d
>   0x25cc6821 0x26192411 0x25cc66db 0x25cc65a1 0x25cc643d 0x2624922f
>   0x26248643 0x26246cc1 0x261929a1 0x261927b3 0x2db541a9 0x29943635
>   0x8b03f 0x34cdbaaf)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException
>
> (lldb)

Я конечно понимаю что из-за несуществующего значения, но не знаю как решить.

Comment: У вас тут код странно отформатирован (отступы вразброс), это затрудняет чтение вопроса. Пожалуйста, приведите его в порядок.

Comment: Ну, попросите того, кто написал код `updateTitle`, модифицировать его. Или гляньте в раздел «строковые операции» в любом учебнике по языку.

Comment: Кстати, ваш формат неоднозначен, вы знаете? Что сделает ваш код, если придёт трек исполнителя «Би - 2»?

Comment: @VladD оно выведет  **Би** и **2** но обычно в Исполнителях перед и в конце тире пробелы не ставятся, но даже если и так то такие случаи очень редкие.

Comment: @Ve4no_molodoy: Ну да, редкие, это правда. Но проблема возможна, это собственно и значит, что формат неоднозначен.

Comment: @VladD А что если сделать вот так?будет ли эффект. просто проверить не могу это нужно ждать пока на радио новости пойдут `   NSString *title_track_empty = @"";
    

    if ([piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1]) {
        NSLog(@"Название трека Найдено! Трек: %@", title_track);
        self.trackTitle.text = title;
        self.trackTitle_label.text = title_track;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Название трека не найдено!");
        self.trackTitle.text = title;
        self.trackTitle_label.text = title_track_empty;
    }`

Comment: @Ve4no_molodoy: А вы можете модифицировать код, чтобы он создал вам фейковую новость? Тогда не обязательно дожидаться радио.

Comment: @VladD проблему решил. Спасибо за наводку на «строковые операции». Ответ с вариантом решения тоже кинул

Comment: @Ve4no_molodoy: Отлично, что решили! У вас мой +1.

Comment: Для случаев "Би - 2" я себе заводил список замен на варианты без пробелов

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился таким способом:

```
-(void)updateTitle:(NSString*)title {

NSArray *piecesOfOriginalString = [title componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];


NSString *title_track_empty = @"[App.fm]";

if ([piecesOfOriginalString count] >= 2) {


    NSString *title_artist = [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"StreamTitle='(.*)"
                                                                                                 withString:@"$1"
                                                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0] length])];


    NSString *title_track = [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(.*)';" withString:@"$1"
                                                                                                   options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:1] length])];

    self.trackTitle.text = title_artist;
    self.trackTitle_label.text = title_track;
}
else {
    NSString *title_artist_one = [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"StreamTitle='(.*)';"
                                                                                                     withString:@"$1"
                                                                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [[piecesOfOriginalString objectAtIndex:0] length])];

    self.trackTitle.text = title_artist_one;
    self.trackTitle_label.text = title_track_empty;
}
```

}

т.е в случае если у нас в массиве только **Исполнитель**, то в место названия трека будет надпись "**App fm**"! Всем спасибо!